# List won't come up in my App

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on a tutorial to try to get use to Android Studios. The App I'm making is suppose to search a database for books and then show a list of the results. But when I run the App while it claims to be a success it doesn't print the list.

Here is my MainActivity.java class:

```
    package com.example.dpolaristar.omgandroid;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
    import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;

    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements     
    View.OnClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener  {

TextView mainTextView;
Button mainButton;
EditText mainEditText;
ListView mainListView;
JSONAdapter mJSONAdapter;
ArrayList mNameList = new ArrayList();
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
private static final String PREFS = "prefs";
private static final String PREF_NAME = "name";
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private static final String QUERY_URL = "http://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // 1. Access the TextView defined in layout XML
    // and then set its text
    mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
    // 2. Access the Button defined in layout XML
    // and listen for it here
    mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    mainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    // 3. Access the EditText defined in layout XML
    mainEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_edittext);
    // 4. Access the ListView
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);

    // 5. Set this activity to react to list items being pressed
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    // 7. Greet the user, or ask for their name if new
    displayWelcome();
    // 10. Create a JSONAdapter for the ListView
    mJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());

    // Set the ListView to use the ArrayAdapter
    mainListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu.
    // Adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Access the Share Item defined in menu XML
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Access the object responsible for
    // putting together the sharing submenu
    if (shareItem != null) {
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    }

    // Create an Intent to share your content
    setShareIntent();

    return true;
}
private void setShareIntent() {

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {

        // create an Intent with the contents of the TextView
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android Development");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mainTextView.getText());

        // Make sure the provider knows
        // it should work with that Intent
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // 9. Take what was typed into the EditText and use in search
    queryBooks(mainEditText.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


}

public void displayWelcome() {

    // Access the device's key-value storage
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Read the user's name,
    // or an empty string if nothing found
    String name = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_NAME, "");

    if (name.length() > 0) {

        // If the name is valid, display a Toast welcoming them
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome back, " + name + "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        // otherwise, show a dialog to ask for their name
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Hello!");
        alert.setMessage("What is your name?");

        // Create EditText for entry
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        // Make an "OK" button to save the name
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                // Grab the EditText's input
                String inputName = input.getText().toString();

                // Put it into memory (don't forget to commit!)
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                e.putString(PREF_NAME, inputName);
                e.commit();

                // Welcome the new user
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome, " + inputName + "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Make a "Cancel" button
        // that simply dismisses the alert
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}
        });

        alert.show();
    }
    }
private void queryBooks(String searchString) {

    // Prepare your search string to be put in a URL
    // It might have reserved characters or something
    String urlString = "";
    try {
        urlString = URLEncoder.encode(searchString, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        // if this fails for some reason, let the user know why
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Create a client to perform networking
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    // Have the client get a JSONArray of data
    // and define how to respond
    client.get(QUERY_URL + urlString,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    // Display a "Toast" message
                    // to announce your success
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // update the data in your custom method.
                    mJSONAdapter.updateData(jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs"));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {
                    // Display a "Toast" message
                    // to announce the failure
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Log error message
                    // to help solve any problems
                    Log.e("omg android", statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
}
```

And here is my other class JSONAdapter.java:

```
    package com.example.dpolaristar.omgandroid;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    /**
    * Created by dpolaristar on 1/11/2016.
    */
    public class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String IMAGE_URL_BASE =  
    "http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/";

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    JSONArray mJsonArray;

public JSONAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = inflater;
    mJsonArray = new JSONArray();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mJsonArray.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mJsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // your particular dataset uses String IDs
    // but you have to put something in this method
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    // check if the view already exists
    // if so, no need to inflate and findViewById again!
    if (convertView == null) {

        // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_book, null);

        // create a new "Holder" with subviews
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.thumbnailImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        holder.authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_author);

        // hang onto this holder for future recyclage
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        // skip all the expensive inflation/findViewById
        // and just get the holder you already made
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // More code after this
    // Get the current book's data in JSON form
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) getItem(position);

    // See if there is a cover ID in the Object
    if (jsonObject.has("cover_i")) {

        // If so, grab the Cover ID out from the object
        String imageID = jsonObject.optString("cover_i");

        // Construct the image URL (specific to API)
        String imageURL = IMAGE_URL_BASE + imageID + "-L.jpg";

        // Use Picasso to load the image
        // Temporarily have a placeholder in case it's slow to load
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageURL).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_books).into(holder.thumbnailImageView);
    } else {

        // If there is no cover ID in the object, use a placeholder
        holder.thumbnailImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_books);
    }
    // Grab the title and author from the JSON
    String bookTitle = "";
    String authorName = "";

    if (jsonObject.has("title")) {
        bookTitle = jsonObject.optString("title");
    }

    if (jsonObject.has("author_name")) {
        authorName = jsonObject.optJSONArray("author_name").optString(0);
    }

    // Send these Strings to the TextViews for display
    holder.titleTextView.setText(bookTitle);
    holder.authorTextView.setText(authorName);

    return convertView;
}
public void updateData(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    // update the adapter's dataset
    mJsonArray = jsonArray;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
// this is used so you only ever have to do
// inflation and finding by ID once ever per View
private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnailImageView;
    public TextView titleTextView;
    public TextView authorTextView;
}
}
```

If you need to see any other code or need any more questions answered I'll provide them.

Here is the tutorial I'm on for reference in case they are doing something wrong or if you want to check if I missed a step. (Although I have already checked.)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78578/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-3

Comment: This may be contributing, change `JSONAdapter mJSONAdapter;` to `final JSONAdapter mJSONAdapter`.

Comment: You should try to get a log for `jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs")`, just to see if it isn't returning a null object. And you also should try to test with `getJSONArray()` instead of `optJSONArray()`, just to be sure.

Comment: This might not change something in this situation, @RichardPoole, because this should be underlined and provide an error if `final` is required.

Comment: Also I'd wrap the `mJSONAdapter.updateData(jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs"));` in a `getApplicationContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
mJSONAdapter.updateData(jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs")); });`

Comment: @RichardPoole complains with an error plus I think it needs to be a variable rather then a constant.

Comment: You get a clue @RichardPoole. This might be a thread problem. The adapter will not be updated until it will do in UI thread. I think this can be the solution.

Comment: @Fllo how do I get this log and test them?

Comment: Something like the following: `Log.v( "JSON", "docs = "+jsonObject.optArray("docs").toString() );` and/or `if (jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs") == null) Log.v("JSON", "JsonArray is null");` - it will be print on LogCat console.

Comment: Where do I add this code in the file?

Comment: @dpolaristar i've edited my answer below, should work for you now.

Comment: @Fllo I tried the if (jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs") == null) Log.v("JSON", "JsonArray is null"); I got nothing on my Logcat actually every time I've ever run my LogCat I've gotten nothing. Would you like to see what I get on my event logs or Gradle console because I get info there.

Comment: So the log doesn't show up because it's not null. That's a good news. I think this is definitely a problem with the adapter.

Comment: What is the adapter? Is that the link between the studio(in my computer) And the App(On the Tablet?) How do you know that is the problem? Explain what I can do to remedy the problem. Anyone else agree or disagree with @Fllo here?

Comment: @Fllo forgive me I had just got up and my head wasn't in yet. By adapter you mean the JSONAdapter.java class right? Well I checked and I followed the tutorial so I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: No problem, I was responding. At first I was thinking about the non update in UI Thread (like RichardPoole's awser) but that's not the case. `onSuccess` returns a result in main thread, I saw in documentation. I now suspect your `updateData()` in the adapter, but I'm not sure enough to get a solution. I'll see, and come back if I have a proper solution.

Comment: @Fllo anything yet it's been over a week, been working on other projects waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Amend the following code:

```
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                // Display a "Toast" message
                // to announce your success
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // update the data in your custom method.
                mJSONAdapter.updateData(jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs"));
            }
```

to:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    final JSONObject finalJsonObject = jsonObject;
    // Display a "Toast" message
    // to announce your success
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // update the data in your custom method.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mJSONAdapter.updateData(finalJsonObject.optJSONArray("docs"));
        }
    });
}
```

You'll also need to change

```
JSONAdapter mJSONAdapter;
```

to:

```
final JSONAdapter mJSONAdapter;
```

Switch the following two around in onCreate:

```
// 7. Greet the user, or ask for their name if new
displayWelcome();
// 10. Create a JSONAdapter for the ListView
mJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());
```

So they become:

```
// 7. Greet the user, or ask for their name if new
mJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());
// 10. Create a JSONAdapter for the ListView
displayWelcome();
```

Comment: complains with two errors one for (new Runnable(): Class 'Anonymous.class derived from Runnable' menu either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'run()' in 'Runnable' 
And another error for jsonObject.optJSONArray which reads: Variable 'jsonObject' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.

Comment: @dpolaristar have you tried the edited version. Also, you'll need to make jsonObject and mJSONAdapter final.

Comment: Variable 'jsonObject' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.  comes up.

Comment: Complains with the error: variable 'mJSONAdapter' may not have been initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Put these lines inside `queryBooks() => onSuccess()`:

```
mJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());
mainListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapter);
```

Comment: complains with an error on (this, getLayoutInflator()); which reads as:

JSONAdaptor(android.content.Context,       LayoutInflator) in JSONApadter cannot be applied to     )anonymous com.loopj.android.http.JSONHttpResponseHandler, LayoutInflator)

Comment: Replace `this` with `MainActivity.this`

Comment: There were no errors but when I ran the App it made no difference and the results were the same.